# How to add some extra fields to the user in django-cms? (in django admin panel)

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I would like to add some extra fields to user in django-cms (in django admin panel). How to do this in the simplest way?

Need to add two fields user bio and image. And can i use this in frontend to show a page with all the user info?

Answer (score 0):

From the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Create you custom user model like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Change the admin file like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from my_user_profile_app.models import Employee

# Define an inline admin descriptor for Employee model
# which acts a bit like a singleton
class EmployeeInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Employee
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'employee'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (EmployeeInline, )

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

**OR**

Another option is to define a custom user model. For more details please visit https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

Comment: I am doing the same way but don't know why "User edit" link in admin not working. It takes me to the front end with Page not found error.

Comment: Where is admin.py file is located?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model):

The simplest way would be to create what is often called a profile model. So for your example you would create something like

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    bio = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
```

Then, for seeing this in the admin panel, you would reregister admin for the User

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from my_user_profile_app.models import Profile

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'profile'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline, )

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

As far as showing this in frontend, you can use User as well as Profile the same way you would use other Django models.